# Как добавить разделитель "-" между цифрами?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть цифры `077777777`.

Хочу делать так, чтобы был:

```
077-77-77-77
```

Как это делать?

Надо сделать с помощю Regex.
Я попробовал так:

```
let numbers = str.match(?:[^-]|^)(1(?:-1)+)(?!-)
```

Comment: покажите, пожалуйста, что вы пробовали сделать

Answer (score 5):

На основе популярного выражения для добавления разрядов:

```js
let rExp = /(^\d{3}|\d)(?=(\d{2})+([^\d]|$))/g;

console.log('12366'.replace(rExp, '$1-'));
console.log('077777777'.replace(rExp, '$1-'));
console.log('1234567890'.replace(rExp, '$1-'));
console.log('5101010101010101010'.replace(rExp, '$1-'));
```

Comment: Блеск! Красавчик!

Comment: @Zugr: спасибо. Я лишь подправил под конкретную задачу, а регулярку эту ещё лет десять назад отыскал.

Answer (score 4):

```
let str2 = "012345678"; console.log(str2.match(/0?\d\d/g).join('-'));
```

покрутил немного с разными входными данными есть вариант более качественный:

```js
let str2 = "01234500678";
console.log([...[...str2].reverse().join('').split(/(\d\d)/).map(function(v, i) { return i != 0 && v=='' ? '-' : v; }).join('')].reverse().join(''));
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно так:

```js
const str = "077777777"; 
console.log(str.match(/0?\d{2}/g).join`-`);
```

Либо так по приколу:

```js
const str = "077777777";
console.log(str[0] + [...str].slice(1).reverse().map((e,i)=>i%2!==0?e+'-':e).join``.slice(0,-1));
```

Comment: потестируйте  на "012340056".